# Why I'm getting - Rendered more hooks than during the previous render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a hook named useComments.

When I hardcode,

```
const { comments1 } = useComments(requests[l].id, true);
const { comments2 } = useComments(requests[l].id, true);
const { comments3 } = useComments(requests[l].id, true);
```

**I'm getting desired output.**

But When I use **for loop** for getting ID stored in an array I'm getting **'Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.'** Error.

```
for (let l = 0; l < 2; l++) {
  const { comments } = useComments(requests[l].id, true);
  console.log({ [l]: comments });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation on React hooks and happens because the number of hooks **inside a single component before return** must be constant.

What you can do - just break it up into a component that has a constant number of hooks - just one:

```
function Comments({ requestId }) {
  const { comments } = useComments(requestId, true);
  console.log({ [l]: comments });
  
  return null
}

function Wrapper() {
  const requestIds = []
  for (let l = 0; l < 2; l++) {
    requestIds.push(requests[l].id)
  }
  // note we don't use any hooks here.
  
  return requestIds.map((requestId) => <Comments requestId={requestId} />
}
```